# for real numbers w, x, y, and z. prove for x, z ≠ 0, (w/x)(y/z)=(wy)/(xz) and (w/x)+(y/z)=(wz+xy)/(xz)

Tags: analysis

I'm lost with the assignment from my teacher. 
For real numbers w, x, y, and z. Prove for x,z≠0, (w/x)(y/z)=(wy)/(xz) and (w/x)+(y/z)=(wz+xy)/(xz)

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$\frac{w}{x}+\frac{y}{z}=\frac{wz}{xz}+\frac{xy}{xz}=…$$
$$\frac{w}{x}\cdot \frac{y}{z}=\frac{wy}{xz}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, can you elaborate